# Error: Reverse for 'get_detail' not found. 'get_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am new to Django and facing the following issue.

My Template file index.html:

```
<a href = "{% url 'polls:get_detail' question.id %}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Vote</a>
```

I am passing question.id to the url and my urls.py:

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>',views.get_detail, name='get_datail')
    ]
```

and part of my views.py:

```
 def get_detail(request,question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question not exist")
    return render(request,'polls/result.html',{ 'question':question })
```

After running this I am getting below error:

**Reverse for 'get_detail' not found. 'get_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

I am using Django version : 3.0.3. 
Thank you.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your urls: The name there is 'get_datail' (with an "a") and not 'get_detail'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a type error.

In your template you have `'polls:get_detail'`, and in your urls.py you named your url `name='get_datail'`

Comment: I didn't recognized it! Thank you so much :)